# How to give administrative permissions to some users in PARSE

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using ParseUser service to mange users in my system, 
and need to add the ability to give administrative permissions to some users.
The administrative users need to be able to use all CRUD operations on the users table.

How can I do it using parse?

Today when logged as user1 and using CRUD operations on user2 I get errors back from parse.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is; you can use the Parse master key in Cloud code and delegate the administration functions to parse cloud. Then via differentiating users (for example whose type is admin) can trigger the cloud function in your application. Hope this helps.

Regards.